# How to get the id of a model in octobercms

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I am creating a popular list of categories in octobercms and have this

```
function onStart(){




$cat = Cat::find($id)->increment('view_count'); //<--> How do i get this $id so it increments the category view_count using the id?

 $this['trending'] = Cat::orderBy('view_count')->where('parent_id', '>', 0)->take(10)->get(); 



}
```

How do i retrieve the $id to use in the query?

Comment: No i am not using any route. Just want to display the popular list on the home page

Answer (score 0):

```
$cat = Cat::select('id')->get();  or  $cat = Cat::get();
return view('abc', comopact('cat'));
```

in your view

```
{{count($cat->id)}}
```

or

```
function onStart(Cat $id){
    $cat = Cat::where('id', $id)->increment('view_count')->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any route for this function?
You can pass $id in the function

```
function onStart($id){
 dd($id);
}
```